# finding eigenvalues of $AB$ when $A$ an $B$ commute.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that if $A$ and $B$ are commuting $n*n$ real matrices, then each eigenvalue of $AB$ is a product of some eigenvalue of $A$ with some eigenvalue of $B$.

I know the fact that since $AB=BA$ , $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvector but I could not use it.

Comment: Using the fact that $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvector, conclude that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously upper-triangularizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two matrices which commute are simultaneously triangularizable, i.e., there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that both $A'=PAP^{-1}$ and $B'=PBP^{-1}$ are upper triangular. Now we can show:
$$
AB = P^{-1}A'PP^{-1}B'P=P^{-1}A'B'P
$$
$A'B'$ is still upper triangular. The diagonal entries of an upper triangular matrix are just its eigenvalues which are unaffected by a similarity transformation (that is, taking $PA'B'P^{-1}$), so the eigenvalues of $AB$ are products of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I thought about it. But the matrix is real. Can we still talk about trianagulazation?

Comment: Yes: any complex square matrix is triangularizable. Real matrices can be seen as a particular case of complex matrices. The eigenvalues may not be real, but everything still works, it's just that $P, A', B'$ might not have real entries.